# How do you SELECT from two databases simultaneously?

Tags: php, mysql

Assume I create 2 MySQLi objects `$db1` and `$db2`.

The connections reside on different servers (locally) and the database structures are identical. I would like to query both servers with the same query.

My questions are:

1. Can I query the databases simultaneously?
2. What are some effective ways of combining the results?

Some insights or point to the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to do this if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: creating a sharding platform

Comment: I am not sure if MySQL supports sharding, but if it does then you should configure MySQL so that it handles it. Implementing sharding is not a trivial matter, and doing it in PHP is probably not a good idea in any case.

Comment: im sharding at the application level, mysql will be oblivious to the presence of other databases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start two threads (one to query each DB), join both threads, then process the result.

PHP support for threads is available via extensions such as:

http://php.net/gearman

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpthreadlib/

https://github.com/kulikov/php-threads-manager

https://github.com/dlsniper/php-threads

https://github.com/unusorin/php-threads

I know you state that you want to do app level sharding.  I would argue (having done it) that app level sharding is non-trivial.  Easy enough to setup initially, but complex when you need to add a new shard (migrating key ranges to the new server while the app is online is not trivial).  At least have a look at MySQL support for sharding and partitioning: http://xeround.com/blog/2011/11/mysql-sharding-vs-mysql-partitioning

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: Added Gearman to the answer.  Thanks for pointing that out.